# Add Rol in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

Can I add Rol on the fly in symfony2 on the InteractiveLoginEvent? Or can I put in the security.yml on the access_control definition in `roles:` a string like this `ROLE_INTRANET_*`?

Comment: If you solved your problem, please rewrite your comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I solved my problem, I just modify the function getRoles like this ...`public function getRoles() { $rol = new \THEBUNDLE\Entity\AclRoles(); $rol->setRol("ROLE_INTRANET"); $this->addRole($rol); return $this->getUserRoles()->toArray(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... You can add role to user on the InteractiveLoginEvent:

```
...
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
    $user->addRole('ROLE_INTRANET');
    $event->getAuthenticationToken()->setUser($user);
    ...
}
...
```

Method addRole should be implemented in user class.

One question: why would you want to add a role? For what purpose?

Comment: [answer]Because these ROLES are statics and they aren't in the Database. For example if an user has a success login through the EXTRANET access, the app load all the roles that the user have, and one extra ROLE called ROLE_EXTRANET. The last ROLE is in the file "security.yml" in the section access_control (  path: ^/extranet/.*, role: ROLE_EXTRANET, requires_channel: https ) which allow to navigate in the apps that have a prefix ^/extranet/.*